# How to store AWS S3 object data to a postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, go, amazon-s3

I'm working on a Golang application where users will be able to upload files:Images & PDFs.
The files will be stored in AWS S3 bucket which I've implemented. However I dont know how to go about retrieving identifiers for the stored items to save them in Postgres.
I was thinking of using an item.ID but the AWS sdk for go method does not provide an object ID:

```
for _,item:=range response.Contents{
        log.Printf("Name : %s\n",item.Key)
        log.Printf("ID : %s\n",*item.)

    }
```

What other options are available to retrieve stored object references from AWS S3?

Comment: I personally would simply store the bucket name and the object key. If the bucket name is a constant and easily inferred then just the object key. You know the object key because you have to supply it when uploading to S3.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to [event source a lambda with an S3 bucket event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html). This way, you can get more details about the object created within your bucket. Then you can make this lambda function to persist the object metadata into postgres

Another option would be simply to append the object key you are using in your SDK to the bucket name you're targeting, then the final result would be full URI that points to the object stored. Something like this

```
s3://{{BUCKET_NAME/{{OBJECT_KEY}}
```